# Show value to the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hidden-field

I would like to show the data that has been passed by the hidden fields on a page. 
    For example, I put a hidden field on page1 and then sends it on page2 then I added another value hidden field. I want to see all hidden data on page3. 
    thank you

```
page1

<%= form_tag( prenotazione_path, method: "post") do %>
 <%= hidden_field_tag "titolo", params[:titolo] %>
<%= submit_tag "PRENOTA" %>
<% end %>

page2

<p>
  <strong>Titolo:</strong>
   ......???
</p>
```

Comment: Which technology r u using?

Comment: ruby on rails 4 and use hidden_field_tag to pass value on form_tag

Comment: please be more specific..no one can answer like this.

Comment: Ah ok! I want this: show on an page a hidden fied value. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That is possible. Please see this code,

page1

```
<%= form_tag( page2_path, method: "post") do %>
 <%= hidden_field_tag "value1", "value1" %>
<%= submit_tag "PRENOTA" %>
<% end %>
```

page2

```
<%= form_tag( page3_path, method: "post") do %>
 <%= hidden_field_tag "value1", params[:value1] %>
 <%= hidden_field_tag "value2", "value2 %>
<%= submit_tag "PRENOTA" %>
<% end %>
```

Page3

```
<p>
  <strong>Values:</strong>
   <%= params[:value1] %>
   <%= params[:value2] %>
</p>
```

I don't know why you need this approach. Use sessions instead.

Comment: Please i have some problem: i have some hidden field wich take a lot of value on array. I try to show it in page3 but i don't see nothing